# JQuery clone click add more button if i select the previous row date not updating and when click delete the top total result value was not reducing

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Currently I am working with jquery clone and calculating from date and to date displaying in the top of the panel using date picker. With my curernt code I am able to clone the row and add the two date values but when I click the delete button it is deleting the cloned row but it is not updating the total result label in the top of my example.

Here is my code for delete button:

```
$(document).on('click', ".btn_less1", function() {
  var len = $('.cloned-row3').length;
  if (len > 1) {
    var RemoveStartDate = $(this).closest(".btn_less1").parent().parent().parent().find('.startDate ').val();
    var RemoveEndDate = $(this).closest(".btn_less1").parent().parent().parent().find('.endDate  ').val();

    if ((RemoveStartDate != '') || (RemoveEndDate != '')) {
      var dateStartArray = RemoveStartDate.split('/'),
        dateEndArray = RemoveEndDate.split('/');
      var fromdate = new Date(dateStartArray[2], dateStartArray[0] - 1, dateStartArray[0]),
        todate = new Date(dateEndArray[2], dateEndArray[0] - 1, dateEndArray[0]);

      var yearsDifference = todate.getFullYear() - fromdate.getFullYear();
      var monthsDifference = (todate.getMonth() + 12 * todate.getFullYear()) - (fromdate.getMonth() + 12 * fromdate.getFullYear());

      var PrevTotalYear = parseInt($("#txt_expy>span").text());
      var PrevTotalMonth = parseInt($("#txt_expm>span").text());


      $("#txt_expy>span").text('');
      $("#txt_expm>span").text('');

      PrevTotalYear = PrevTotalYear * 12;

      var CurTotalYear = Math.floor(((PrevTotalYear + PrevTotalMonth) - monthsDifference) / 12);
      var CurTotalMonth = (monthsDifference - PrevTotalMonth) % 12;


      $("#txt_expy>span").text(CurTotalYear);
      $("#txt_expm>span").text(CurTotalMonth);
      $(this).closest(".btn_less1").parent().parent().parent().remove();
    } else {
      $(this).closest(".btn_less1").parent().parent().parent().remove();
    }
  }
});
```

When the user selects **from date as 12/01/2000 and to date as 12/01/2003**

the result will be Total work experience 3Years 0Month

and if the user clicks add more button it will create one more row

and again **from date as 12/01/2004 and to date as 12/01/2015**

the result will be Total work experience 15Years 0Months with my code. This works as I would expect it.

When the user clicks the delete button it is deleting the row but it is not updating the Total work experience and if I click add more button if I try to modify the previous from date and to date it is not updating in the result either.

Here is the [fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/bqgjro6d/40/)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Thats quite a title you got there.

Comment: @AtheistP3ace :) can you please look the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the original HTML starts like this:

```
<label class="years_lab" id="txt_expy"><span>0</span>Years</label>
```

When the values are changed you set the value like this:

```
document.getElementById("txt_expy").innerHTML
```

Which sets the inside of the label and removes the span element. And when you try to recalculate the  total you select it like this:

```
$("#txt_expy>span")
```

But this returns an empty jQuery object since the span doesn't exist anymore.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bqgjro6d/41/

I changed the last two lines from:

```
document.getElementById("txt_expy").innerHTML = diffYears;
document.getElementById("txt_expm").innerHTML = diffMonths;
```

To:

```
$("#txt_expy>span").text(diffYears);
$("#txt_expm>span").text(diffMonths);
```

Comment: So if i remove the span tag and related span tag this will work i tried several other thing nothing was working  buddy kindly please update in the fiddle

Comment: thanks buddy one issue solved with your code one more issue if the user initally add the exp and then click new row then if the user want to modify the previos row it was not updating kindly please help me that also :(

Comment: any luck buddy for the one which i asked

Comment: Its because you determine updating the total based on every field having a value. Once you enter a date into every field it will calculate the total.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking me to change? You have code that says if this field value == "" then return from the change event. I have no idea what your requirements are. Honestly your code is complex for trying to do something so simple.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97224/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-atheistp3ace).